# Language sensitive italicized quotation with csquotes

Tags: formatting, languages, italic, quoting, csquotes

In what follows:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{IndentFirst=false}
\begin{document}
text in French \foreignblockquote{english}[][.]{quotation in English} text in French text \blockquote[][.]{quotation in French}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the quotation in English italicized. It is obviously possible to use `\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{\emph{#1}#2#4#3}` but it will affect all the block-like quotations. I had a quick look in the `csquotes.sty` file but it is too complicated for me. I also had a look at the conditional statements available in the package but none are language-related.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In both `\mktextquote` and `\mkblockquote`, add

```
\iflanguage{english}{\itshape}{}
```

at the appropriate position. (`\iflanguage` is a `babel` conditional.)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt]{book}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{%
  #1%
  \iflanguage{english}{\itshape}{}% ADDED
  #2#4#3#6#5%
}
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[4]{%
  \iflanguage{english}{\itshape}{}% ADDED
  #1#2#4#3%
}

\begin{document}

text in French
\foreignblockquote{english}[][.]{quotation in English}
text in French
\blockquote[][.]{quotation in French}
text in French
\foreignblockquote{english}[][.]{quotation \\in \\English}
text in French
\blockquote[][.]{quotation \\in \\French}
text in French

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please also add an example how to make all uses of `\foreignlanguage` italicized?

Comment: Just realized that the quotes of the quotation in English are wrong. Can probably be fixed easily.